# Ionauth first time a user logs in + resend activation mail

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

I currently have Ion_auth implemented in my codeigniter project. After a registration, an email is send to activate the account.

Currently I am facing two problems.

*How to resend the activation email ?
*How to check if it's the first time a user does a login on the website ?

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

*How to resend the activation email?*

You have to write few line of code to cover this function, take a look at the register method

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/libraries/Ion_auth.php#L292

*How to check if it's the first time a user does a login on the website?*

Also here you have to implement this function by yourself: for example ad a new field to the table `user` of type datetime named first_login. When the user login you will check if is empty in this case you INSERT the first login.

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/controllers/auth.php#L53